# Error en la ejecución de mi proyecto Spring Framework MVC

Tags: java, netbeans, spring, netbeans-8.2

Tengo un proyecto Java web con SPRING FRAMEWORK MVC, cuando quiero depurarlo en Google Chrome me sale el siguiente error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:

> Browser defused to debug this tab. Close Chrome Developer Tool (or any other browser debugger) and try again.

Y además sale este error que impide que aparezca el CSS:

> Did not parse stylesheet at 'http://localhost:8084/spring_mvc_pruebas_2/recursos/estilos/miestilo.css' because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode. (15:02:55:604 | error, security)
>   Debugging session with browser was closed.

Comment: Hola persinao134567 ¿podrias colocar algo de tu código?. Lo suficiente para poder reproducir en ambiente local el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Este es un error de netbeans en particular, hay muchas soluciones propuestas que incluyen

- [cerrar el tab manualmente antes de correr por segunda vez](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=233496)
- [seleccionar el icnono de chrome que se corre con cordova](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9DSDqjemxY)
- [Seleccionar Chrome como navegador predeterminado en opciones y reiniciar el IDE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKMob8U3weQ)
- Consultar la misma página en dos tabs, parar la ejecución y volver a correr

El problema en sí reside en el conector, que es un plugin de Chrome, que desconecta la sesión de depuración y elimina el DOM que teníamos, por lo que al correr por segunda vez tenemos un DOM vacío leído desde Netbeans y el error se manifiesta.